# Человек вводит логин, и его перекидывает на окно с оплатой. Как это реализовать? Python Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
elif message.text == ' Пополнить Steam ':
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEGI4JjT_urhtc_U7VJhCpM3jXOqsrq2gACEQADDkfHKHeBfoYMOnnDKgQ')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите Ваш логин Steam.\n(Что такое логин, можно узнать во вкладке ` FAQ`)',  parse_mode='html')
```

И тут должно быть то, что бот видит, что пользователь написал свой логин и перебрасывал на окно с оплатой.
Примерно вот так, вообще не знаю как это делается. Весь инет прорыл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй

```
elif message.text == ' Пополнить Steam ':
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEGI4JjT_urhtc_U7VJhCpM3jXOqsrq2gACEQADDkfHKHeBfoYMOnnDKgQ')
    # Зачем вы пишите parse_mode вы же его не юзаете?
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите Ваш логин Steam.\n(Что такое логин, можно узнать во вкладке ` FAQ`)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name_steam)

def get_name_steam(message: types.Message):
    name = message.text # <- вот вам и ваш ник
    markup = InlineKeyboarMarkup().add(...)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=markup)
```